# PHP cURL request not sending a file in parameters

Tags: php, html, css, curl, fonts

I'm more than a little confused on what is happening with a cURL request I'm making.

I have an HTML file that is created by my code (works perfectly, and can share example if need be, but I don't think it's needed). This HTML file is then saved and sent via cURL request to a free API from Docverter (documentation link: http://www.docverter.com/api)

Again, this goes perfectly. What I'm running into a problem with is that the custom font file I'm using isn't being passed as well. The API docs say that the "other_files[]" field needs to be set with truetype font file (see: http://www.docverter.com/api#Fonts).

Here is $postfields:

```
array(
    'from' => 'html',
    'to' => 'pdf',
    'input_files[]' => "@/".realpath("$filename").";type=text/x-markdown; charset=UTF-8;}",
    'other_files[]' => "@/".realpath("Helvetica.ttf")
);
```

Where $filename is the filename of the HTML file I generate, and Helvetica.ttf is the filename of the truetype font file I want. Both files are saved in the same location, but Docverter doesn't recognize the font file was uploaded and is still using the default font in the document.

For reference here is the CSS I am posting to Docverter:

```
<style type="text/css">
   <!--
    @page {
      size: 4in 6in;
      margin: 1mm;
  }
  @font-face {
       font-family: "Helvetica";
       font-style: normal;
       font-weight: 400;
       src: url("Helvetica.ttf");
       -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;
       -fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H;
}
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica";
}
p {
line-height: 1.5;
}
  -->
</style>
```

The only think I can think of that I don't have a full multipart/form-data for my Helvetica.ttf in the other_files[] field, but I'm not sure what else I would include since the examples on Docverter don't include that information. Can someone please help?

Thanks!